# $\{{(x,K) : x \in K}\}$ is closed in $X \times \{\text{closed subsets of }X\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact (and Hausdorff, if needed) space. Let's denote the closed subsets of $X$ by $C(X)$, equipped with the Hausdorff topology.

I want to prove that $F=\{{(x,K) : x \in K , K \in C(X)}\}$ is a closed subset of $X \times C(X)$.

Usually I attack these kind of problems by drawing but somehow this time $X$ and $C(X)$ are too related. It is quite difficult to see how F looks like.

I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, can you remind, how is the Hausdorff topology defined on $C(X)$?

Comment: Maybe the so-called H-topology by Fell? This is defined for locally compact spaces normally, so seems a good fit. See http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-03/S0002-9939-1962-0139135-6/S0002-9939-1962-0139135-6.pdf

Comment: Oh I am very sorry for the late respond, and @HennoBrandsma thanks for the lovely answer, that was what I meant exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you mean the $H$-topology as defined by Fell [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-03/S0002-9939-1962-0139135-6/S0002-9939-1962-0139135-6.pdf), usually now called the Fell-topology on $C(X)$. With this I can show $F$ to be closed quite easily:

Recall that a base for this topology on $C(X)$ is provided by all sets of the form $$\langle C; \{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}\rangle = \{A \in C(X): A \cap C = \emptyset, \forall i \in \{1,\ldots n\} U_i \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$$

where $C \subset X$ is a compact subset, and all $U_i$ are (non-empty) open subsets of $X$. The family of open sets is also allowed to be empty. So a basic open set consists of all closed sets that miss a given compact set and hit all open sets from a finite family.

Now let $(x,K) \in X \times C(X)$ such that $(x,K) \notin F$, as defined above. This means that $x \notin K$. By local compactness of $X$ and closedness of $K$, we find a compact $C$ such that $x \in \operatorname{Int}(C)$ and $C \cap K = \emptyset$.

Then $O = \operatorname{Int}(C) \times \langle C; \emptyset \rangle$ is an open set of $X \times C(K)$ such that for all $(p,A)$ in it we have that $p \in \operatorname{Int}(C)$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$, so certainly $p \notin A$, so $(x,K) \in O \subset (X \times C(X)) \setminus F$. This shows that $F$ is closed.